# Application Fails to Load after enabling jdbc based session persistence

Tags: redhat, jboss-eap-7

I  am doing a POC  with JBoss EAP 7.1 release wherein I have enabled db based session persistence, I have tested with the default cache manager persistence and it works well but somehow it doesn't stores any session data in the database schema, however the table gets created at the start of the server which I could see, for this I am starting with the sample counter.war which is present in the Redhat knowledge base. I am using Oracle 12cR1 database.

One more thing is , I am also not able to see the application  from the console, same  thing when I run the  CLI command to read the resource. When I try to see the deployment under Deployments, it simly complains

Unable to load deployments

Unexpected HTTP response: 500  Request { "operation" => "read-children-resources", "address" => undefined, "child-type" => "deployment", "include-runtime" => true, "recursive" => true }  Response  Internal Server Error { "outcome" => "failed", "rolled-back" => true }

My server configuration in the standalone-ha.xml for the jdbc store is as below:

```
        <cache-container name="server" aliases="singleton cluster" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">

            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>

            <replicated-cache name="default">

                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>

            </replicated-cache>

        </cache-container>

        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="jdbc" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">

            <transport channel="ee" lock-timeout="60000"/>

            <local-cache name="concurrent">

                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>

            </local-cache>

            <invalidation-cache name="jdbc">

                <binary-keyed-jdbc-store data-source="Session" dialect="ORACLE" fetch-state="false" passivation="false" preload="false" purge="false" shared="true" singleton="false">

           <!-- <transaction mode="BATCH"/>-->

            <property name="database-Type">

                        oracle

                    </property>

                    <binary-keyed-table prefix="sess">

                       <id-column name="ID" type="VARCHAR2(500)"/>

                       <data-column name="DATUM" type="BINARY"/>

                       <timestamp-column name="MAXINACTIVE" type="NUMBER"/>

                       <timestamp-column name="LASTACCESS" type="NUMBER"/>

                       <timestamp-column name="VERSION" type="NUMBER"/>

                    </binary-keyed-table>

                </binary-keyed-jdbc-store>

            </invalidation-cache>

        </cache-container>

        <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="dist" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">

            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>

            <distributed-cache name="dist">

                <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>

                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>

                <file-store/>

            </distributed-cache>
```

The table that gets created is also as below:

TNAME

---

TABTYPE  CLUSTERID

---

BIN$cLKr2H7+eQ3gU1J2QgonwQ==$0

TABLE

SESS_counter_war

TABLE

sess_counter_war

TABLE

FYI, just for my satisfaction I tried by changing the prefix in the standalone-ha.xml so that's why two tables you could see.

Please guide me if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a late reply almost a year after but as it is being said "Better Late than Never" :)

I managed to bring up the application successfully after some days of facing the error initially. I realized that there was some major issue in my configuration. Basically, I  had the below problems:

1. Using distributed cache instead of invalidated cache.
2. Using binary store  instead of string based  store.
3. Invalid column  and  datatypes.

Refer the original post and answer here- https://developer.jboss.org/thread/278374

Answer (score 0):

In EAP 7.1, you should configure session persistence using `string-keyed-jdbc-store` instead of using `binary-keyed-jdbc-store` which is deprecated in this version.

Comment: After changing to string based store while starting up the server, it throws the below error:ISPN008011: Error while creating table; used DDL statement: 'CREATE TABLE "Sess_counter_war" (id VARCHAR NOT NULL, datum BINARY NOT NULL, version BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))': java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis